# What is meant by early initialization of a Singleton class in Java

Tags: java, singleton, lifecycle

I am not quite clear on what is meant by the term Early initialization of a Singleton class. Also it would be helpful to understand the life cycle of a Singleton class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well `Lazy initialization` means that you do not initialize objects until the first time they are used.

`Early initialization` is just reverse, you initialize a singleton upfront at the time of class loading.

There are ways to do early initialization, one is by declaring your singleton as `static`.

Following as an example:

```
public class SingletonClassEarly {
    private static SingletonClassEarly sce = new SingletonClassEarly();
    private SingletonClassEarly() {} // make it private

    public static SingletonClassEarly getInstance() {
        return sce;
    }
}
```

As per the **lifecycle** this singleton is loaded after JVM starts up and when class is initialized. It gets unloaded by JVM when shutting down/exiting.

Comment: Hi Anubhava, what are other ways for early initialization

Comment: @upog: Using `Enum` is another way or injecting singletons using framework like Spring.

Answer (score 6):

**Lazy Initalizaion**

```
 class SingletonClass {

     private static SingletonClass object;
     private SingletonClass () {} 
     public static SingletonClass getInstance(){
        if(object == null){
            object= new SingletonClass (); //Lazy Initalizaion 
        }
        return object;
    }
 }
```

**Early initialization**

```
  class SingletonClass {

     private static SingletonClass object = new SingletonClass (); //Early initialization
     private SingletonClass () {} 

     public static SingletonClass getInstance(){
        return object;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A normally in Singleton  this is what you  see

```
 private static YouClass  singleTon ;

--

--

    public static YouClass getInstance(){
            if(singleTon  == null){
                singleTon  = new YouClass();
            }
            return singleTon  ;
        }
```

In this scenario, when you called `getInstance()`  first time then only `YouClass`  instance get created.

**Early initialization**, That means

In a your class

```
  private static YouClass singleTon = new YouClass();
```

Creating instance while declaring it self.

From [Singleton pattern wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) ,read the  types,

- Lazy initialization
- Eager initialization
- Static block initialization

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the explanation. That helps answer my question.

I also found a couple of useful blog posts which goes in more detail about how different approaches work.

Here are the links:

http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/10/22/singleton-design-pattern-in-java/

The next article helps explain the use of volatile keyword when using the double checked approach:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/volatile-keyword-java-example-tutorial.html